# How can I reuse a local profile when changing domains?

Tags: domain, switch, profile

Client is XP Pro. The user was connected to one domain and had his profile fine-tuned for his needs (Word, Outlook, Excel with lots of rules/customizations/forms, plus customized desktop, of course). User brings his computer to another firm, whith a different server and domain, wants to reuse his profile without any changes. Both servers are Win2k3, profile is local, not roaming.

Is it possible, and if so, can someone give me a step-by-step procedure (or point me to where I can find one)?

I have tried to copy the old profile to the new, default one generated by a login to the new domain, but upon re-login it fails to locate half the Office settings (forms, startup macros, etc).

Thank you

Comment: Evan may have posted what you need here: http://serverfault.com/questions/17832/migrate-local-profiles-to-roaming-profiles

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't without the use of other tools that know how to read all of the settings you're interested in.  Office has a function that will allow you to export / import settings, depending on which version you're using.

Profiles are tied to the domain user that they're created for.    The two accounts will have different SIDs and that's where a lot of things break down for this.  You can't just copy one profile over to the other because a lot of the information is stored in the registry under HKCU, which is just a copy of that user's items under HKEY_USERS, and that is stored according to SID.